# File not found issue on Oreo

Tags: android, directory, file-rename

I am using Huawei Honor 9 Lite handset (Model LLD-AL10) with Android 8.0.0 (EMUI version 8.0.0). At the end of month July 2018 (around 30th or 31st), I had done the below things on my handset:

1. Created a new folder named ".MyData1 (for the hidden folder, used with a dot") on Photos folder (Internal Storage).
2. And inside ".MyData1" folder again created a new folder named ".ImageF1 (used with dot)".
3. Inside the ".ImageF1" folder copied a jpeg file "test1.jpg"
4. Then renamed the "test1.jpg" into "test1.apk"

The file "test1.apk" was there when I checked the same after few days. But when I checked the same file (test1.apk) on the same folder today (26th August 2018) then it is missing. So kindly help me to find the files (test1.apk).

Note: I am using "Security Master" in my handset, is this a problem? If yes then kindly suggest me a better way to recover "test1.apk".

Thanks,
Rajesh

Comment: StackOverflow is a platform about programming questions, if all what you describe above is happening not during writing code in some programming language and testing the program but simply by creating files manually in Android, then you should not ask teh question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, may I know there is any support for this issue in StackOverflow or any other forums, mainly for Android